# Two different data from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables in MySQL are the following: [image]

How to create a SELECT that will show: name and surname of buyer, his comment about buyed thing and name with surname of seller?

So far I've only half of it:

```
SELECT User.name, User.surname, Realization.comment 
FROM User, Realization, Auction, Offer 
WHERE Realization.id_vote = Auction.id_voice AND Auction.id_buyer = User.id_user AND Offer.id_offer=Auction.id_offer;
```

Comment: Edit your question and put it in there.  BTW, you're going to need specific joins instead of automatic joins to get the relationships you need.

Comment: Your Auction table needs an AuctionID unless your database is only going to store one auction at a time.  Unless that's what the Offer table is for.

Comment: Offer table contains all offers, Auction shows people interested in offered products (and a prise they are ready to pay - not shown in the picture). Realization contains only "chosen" by seller proposition. I know Auction table could be better than now, but it's simplified ebay.com database I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a inner join

```
select a.name as buyer_name, a.surname  as buyer_surname, c.comment
    e.name as seller_name, e.surname as seller_surname  
from User as a 
Inner Join Auction as b on b.id_buyer = a.id_user
inner join Realization as c on c.id_voice = b.id_voice
inner join Offer as d on d.id_offer = b.id_offer 
inner join User as e on d.id_seller = e.id_user;
```

Comment: OK, but how to add something between buyer_surname and seller_name? In this case: a comment written by buyer?